# Merge data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, attribute-joins

So I have one table with attributes and adresses and one .shp file with coordinates and adresses can I merge these data in QGIS somehow?

Comment: Would be great if you can share your data with us. Otherwise you may try to join by address field which can be a bit tricky, or what can be more clever is to geocode both of your datasets and then do the join by location with *equals* as a geometric predicate. Gecoding in QGIS is available as a domestic tool, starting from QGIS 3.20. And afterwards do the merge. By "merge" you mean connecting your table with locations?

Comment: You need a common ID between your table and you shape-file. This could be your adress. Without having a look at it, we can't answer for sure.

Comment: As far as the layers have the same geometry, you can merge them without problems.

Answer (score 1):

In gis-terminology this is called 'joining'.  In your case especially an 'attribute-join'.

This can be done in several ways.  In both cases you have to define a field with identical attribute-data in both (your shapefile and your table) on which the join can be performed.

**1/ via layer-properties**

[image]

**2/ via algorithm 'join attributes by field value'**

[image]